# How to create json object data like this - "sales":[{"Debasish":600},{"Sanjana":200}] as column in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench

| date | month | total_employee | total_revenue | total_sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-10-26 | October | 2 | 620.00 | [{"Debasish":500},{"Sanjana":120}] |
| 2022-10-21 | October | 2 | 590.00 | [{"Debasish":300},{"Sanjana":290}] |
| 2022-10-14 | October | 2 | 320.00 | [{"Debasish": 320.00}] |

This is the outcome I'm trying to get from a select query, This is to calculate employee stats, in the last column 'sales' how can i pass the data of every employee work in that business and total revenue generated daily, i want to know how can i show 'total_sales' data like in the shown table.

i've used the JSON_OBJECTAGG like this -

`JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT(emp.name , ad.price)) AS total_sales`

but it returns only 1st price of that day, I need to -

`JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT(emp.name , SUM(ad.price))) AS total_sales`

but its not correct and giving me errors, how can i solve this , also if i can use any other methods please let me know.

```
SET @formDate=DATE_SUB(now(),INTERVAL 30 DAY);

SELECT 
      DATE(appoint.booking_date) AS 'date',
      DATE_FORMAT(appoint.booking_date,'%M') AS 'month',
      (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT emp.id) FROM employee emp WHERE emp.entity_id='126' AND emp.status=1) AS 'total_employee',
      IFNULL(SUM(ad.price),0) AS total_revenue,
      JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT(emp.name , ad.price)) AS total_sales
      FROM employee emp 
      
      LEFT JOIN entity ent ON emp.entity_id=ent.id
      LEFT JOIN appointment_status appstat ON emp.entity_id=appstat.entity_id
      LEFT JOIN appointments appoint ON appstat.appointment_id=appoint.id
      LEFT JOIN appointment_details ad ON appoint.id=ad.appointment_id

      WHERE 
          emp.status=1 AND
          emp.entity_id='126' AND
          appstat.current_status='4' AND
          appstat.assign_to = emp.account_id AND
          DATE_FORMAT(appoint.booking_date,'%Y-%m-%d')
                    BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(@formDate,'%Y-%m-%d') AND 
                            DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%Y-%m-%d') 
      
      GROUP BY
             appoint.booking_date DESC
```

Thanks.

Comment: *This is the outcome I'm trying to get from a select query* This is not valid JSON. Maybe you skip square brackets, and these are element of an array? [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), pp. 3 and 5.

Comment: *"date": "2022-10-26T00:00:00.000Z"* - this is **not** default date format which is used in MySQL. Do you need in it definitely?

Comment: i dont need like that , normal date format would do , i just need to solve the 'sales' part

Comment: Read provided link, provide recommended data.

Comment: @Akina I have corrected the question , please have a look

Comment: Provide source data (CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO) which must result in shown desired output.

Comment: I think that you must aggregate your `appointment_details` in the subquery and calculate `SUM(price)` then join it instead of the table into the query. Now you need 2 gouping levels (sum by appointment and JSON aggregate by date) which cannot be performed in single query. Or maybe in the subquery you'd aggregate appointments tables pack...

Comment: `2022-10-21, October, 2, 590.00, [{"Sanjana Singh": 190.00}, {"Sanjana Singh": 100.00}, {"Debasish": 200.00}, {"Debasish": 100.00}]`

this is the data i'm getting from the query , i just need to sum the values of same name like -
`[{"Sanjana Singh": 290.00},{"Debasish": 300.00}]`

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

```sql
SELECT `date`,
       `month`,
       total_employee,
       total_revenue,
       JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT(name, total_price)) AS total_sales
FROM

-- your query, group by date and name, obtain SUM(prices)
  (
    SELECT DATE(appoint.booking_date) AS `date`,
           DATE_FORMAT(appoint.booking_date, '%M') AS `month`,
           ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT emp.id)
             FROM employee emp
             WHERE emp.entity_id='126'
             AND emp.status=1
             ) AS total_employee,
           IFNULL(SUM(ad.price), 0) AS total_revenue,
           emp.name,
           SUM(ad.price) AS total_price
   FROM employee emp
   LEFT JOIN entity ent ON emp.entity_id=ent.id
   LEFT JOIN appointment_status appstat ON emp.entity_id=appstat.entity_id
   LEFT JOIN appointments appoint ON appstat.appointment_id=appoint.id
   LEFT JOIN appointment_details ad ON appoint.id=ad.appointment_id
   WHERE emp.status=1
     AND emp.entity_id='126'
     AND appstat.current_status='4'
     AND appstat.assign_to = emp.account_id
     AND DATE(appoint.booking_date) 
         BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 30 DAY 
             AND CURRENT_DATE
   GROUP BY `date`,
            emp.name) AS sum_prices

GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
```

Comment: returns :  Error Code: 1055. Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'salonmarket.appoint.booking_date' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: Adjust a part taken from you primary query - it contains this issue, I have not fixed it.

Comment: returns: 
`2022-10-26, October, 2, 620.00, [{"Debasish": 620.00}]`

`2022-10-21, October, 2, 290.00, [{"Sanjana Singh": 290.00}]`

`2022-10-21, October, 2, 300.00, [{"Debasish": 300.00}]`

`2022-10-14, October, 2, 320.00, [{"Debasish": 320.00}]`

`2022-10-13, October, 2, 690.00, [{"Debasish": 690.00}]`

`2022-10-12, October, 2, 840.00, [{"Sanjana Singh": 840.00}]`

`2022-10-12, October, 2, 1870.00, [{"Debasish": 1870.00}]`

Comment: for example - the date - 2022-10-21 has 2 employee worked and its returning 2 rows , what i'm trying to do is, the total_revenue would be 590 and show total_sales [{"Sanjana Singh": 290.00},{"Debasish": 300.00}] , in a single row , instead of 2